# Ajuda com parâmetros TextBox / string

Tags: c#, string, postgresql, textbox

Eu tenho esse método onde eu gostaria de trazer o IBGE.
Quando eu coloco o TextBox como parâmetro, ele traz normalmente, mas o problema é que estou usando uma Library e não consigo importar o TextBox.
Por isso eu substitui o TextBox por uma string, mas dessa forma ele não consegue trazer...
Alguem consegue me ajudar?

```
public bool recuperarIBGE(string Cidade, string IBGE)
    {
        conexao = new Conexao();

        try
        {
            conexao.conectar();
            conexao.abrirConexao();

            NpgsqlCommand sql = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT codibge FROM cidade WHERE nome ilike SEM_ACENTO('" + Cidade + "');", conexao.conexao);

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = sql.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //IBGE.Text = (string)dr["codibge"].ToString();
                IBGE = (string)dr["codibge"].ToString();
                retorno = true;

            }
            conexao.fecharConexao();
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw erro;
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

Comment: onde está o seu erro? é na sua query?

Comment: Na verdade não existe erro, a unica duvida é que ele não consegue retornar nada quando o parametro é uma string.
Já quando é uma TextBox, ele retorna normalmente...
Alguma solução para isso ou eu fiz algo de errado?

Comment: Entendi é porque vi um ilike na sua query e acabei de descobrir que vc usa o banco postgre. Tenta colocar %SEM_ACENTO('" + Cidade + "');%. Repare que add o %

Comment: @Marconi, assim não deu... Teria que ser feito dessa forma então: SEM_ACENTO('%" + Cidade + "%');. Eu testei direto no Postgres e assim ele me retorna varios códigos da cidade =/

Comment: Entendi, estranho isso mais se funcionou tudo bem.

Comment: Mas não posso deixar que traga varios.
 Coloquei Jaú como exemplo na cidade e ele me retornou varias cidades que tem Jaú no meio...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26386/discussion-between-marconi-and-emerson).

Comment: Entra no chat ai.

Comment: Entrei, mas não consigo mandar msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que a alteração no valor no parâmetro `IBGE` seja visível no código que chamou o método você deve definir este parâmetro como `out`.

Simplesmente mude a assinatura do método para

```
public bool recuperarIBGE(string Cidade, out string IBGE)
```

e assegure-se de atribuir um valor em todos os branchs de código do método.

Na hora de chamar o método você também precisa passar o modificador `out` no parâmetro `IBGE`:

```
string ibge;

if (recuperarIBGE("Goiânia", out ibge))
{
    Console.WriteLine("O código IBGE da cidade é" + ibge);
}
```

Dessa forma, após chamar o método `recuperarIBGE` o atributo `IBGE` vai ter o valor que foi atribuído a ele dentro do método.

Comment: Funcionou Amigo, muito obrigado! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Para isso é preciso usar a palavra-chave `ref` ou `out`

[out (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.120).aspx)

[ref (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Obrigado pelos links amigo, ^^